# remove onclick function and change to onload or document.ready

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, prototypejs

What would be the easiest way to remove the onclick event from this script?

The script below uses google translate to translate from one language to another.

I want to be able to set the language to a

```
Request.Form("language")
```

so when I submit a form it will set the language. (I can do this so it is not a problem, however once this language is set I want the script to automatically translate the text.

something like

```
<body onload="">
```

or

```
document.ready or 

translate.ready
```

However I am not 100% sure how to do this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    google.load("language", "1");
    var translator = false;

    function init(){
        var str = $("source").innerHTML;
        var triggerCollection = $("langSelect").select("li");
        triggerCollection.invoke("observe", "click", handleTriggerClick);
        translator = new Translator("source", "p,ul");
        translator.addEventListener("complete", function(obj){
            //console.log("The translation has finished %o", obj);
            {
    document.form1.g_content_text.value = $("source").innerHTML;
    }{
//document.form1.submit();
}
        });
        translator.addEventListener("begin", function(obj){
            //console.log("Translation has begun! %o", obj);        
        });
        //console.log(translator.textNodeCollection);
    }
    function handleTriggerClick(e){
        var lang = e.element().getAttribute("lang"); // This is the language to translate to!
        var str = $("source").innerHTML;
        translator.translate(lang);
    }

    function insertToForeign(obj){      
        $("display").innerHTML = obj.translation;       
    }


    google.setOnLoadCallback(init);

    var Translator = Class.create(EventDispatcher, {
        initialize : function(element, selector, config){
            this.element = $(element);
            this.preservedHTML = this.element.innerHTML;
            this.config = Object.extend(this.getDefaultConfig(), config);           
            this.textNodeCollection = this.collectChildren(selector);
            this.preservedParentHash = {};
            this.placeHolderHash = {};
            this.entityWasher = new Element("div");
            this.textNodeCollection = this.textNodeCollection.findAll(this.purifyTextNode);
        },
        purifyTextNode : function(node){
            try{
                if(!node)
                    return false;
                return node.nodeType == 3;
            }
            catch(e){
                return false;
            }       
        },
        getDefaultConfig : function(){
            return { maxLength : 1000, srcLang : "en", recursive : true, type : "text" };   
        },
        collectChildren : function(selector){
            return this.element.select(selector).collect(this.collectTextNodes.bind(this)).flatten();
        },
        collectTextNodes : function(element){
            var self = this;
            var stack = $A(element.childNodes).collect(function(child){
                if(child.nodeType == 3  && child.nodeValue.length < self.config.maxLength && child.nodeValue.search(/^\s+$/g) == -1)
                    return child;
                else if(child.nodeType == 3  && child.nodeValue.length > self.config.maxLength)
                    return self.splitTextNode(child);
                else if(child.nodeType == 1 && self.config.recursive)
                    return self.collectTextNodes(child);
            });         
            return stack;
        },
        splitStringByMax : function(text){
            var offset = 0;
            var textArr = [];
            while(text.length > this.config.maxLength){             
                var tmp = text.substr(0, this.config.maxLength);
                offset = tmp.lastIndexOf(" ");
                var subText = text.substr(0, offset);               
                text = text.substr(offset);
                textArr.push(subText);              
            }
            textArr.push(text);
            return textArr;
        },
        splitTextNode : function(node){
            var nodeStack = [];
            var textArr = this.splitStringByMax(node.nodeValue);

            var prevNode = false;
            textArr.each(function(text, itr){
                var newNode = document.createTextNode(text);
                nodeStack.push(newNode);        
                if(node.nextSibling != null && !prevNode)
                    node.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, node.nextSibling);
                else if(prevNode && prevNode.nextSibling != null)
                    node.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, prevNode.nextSibling);
                else 
                    node.parentNode.appendChild(newNode);
                prevNode = newNode;
            });
            node.parentNode.removeChild(node);

            return nodeStack;
        },
        getEventBeginObject : function(destLang){
            return { 
                destLang : destLang,
                srcLang : this.config.srcLang,
                srcLangNodes : this.textNodeCollection,
                srcHTML : this.preservedHTML
            }   
        },
        getEventCompleteObject : function(result){
            return {
                srcLangNodes : this.textNodeCollection,
                destLangNodes : this.translationStack,
                destLangHTML : this.element.innerHTML,
                srcLangHTML : this.preservedHTML,
                result : result,
                resultStack : this.resultStack          
            }       
        },
        finishTranslation : function(result){
            this.translating = false;
            this.dispatchEvent("complete", this.getEventCompleteObject(result));

        },
        translate : function(destLang){
            if(this.translating)
                return false;
            var self = this;
            this.dispatchEvent("begin", this.getEventBeginObject(destLang));
            this.textNodeCount = this.textNodeCollection.length;
            this.translationStack = [];
            this.resultStack = [];
            this.textNodeCollection.each(function(node, index){
                self.translating = true;
                google.language.translate(node.nodeValue, self.config.srcLang, destLang, self.handleTranslation.bind(self, node, index));
            });
            return true;    
        },
        getPreservedParent : function(node, index){
            if(this.preservedParentHash[index])
                return this.preservedParentHash[index];
            return this.preservedParentHash[index] = node.parentNode;
        },
        getPlaceHolder : function(index){
            return this.placeHolderHash[index] || false;        
        },
        setPlaceHolder : function(node, index){
            this.placeHolderHash[index] = node;     
        },
        handleTranslation : function(node, index, obj){
            try{
                var parent = this.getPreservedParent(node, index);
                this.entityWasher.innerHTML = obj.translation;
                var translatedText = this.entityWasher.innerHTML;
                if(node.nodeValue.search(/^\s/) > -1)
                    translatedText = " " + translatedText;
                if(node.nodeValue.search(/\s$/) > -1)
                    translatedText = translatedText + " ";

                var newText = document.createTextNode(translatedText);

                if(this.getPlaceHolder(index))
                    parent.replaceChild(newText, this.getPlaceHolder(index));
                else
                    parent.replaceChild(newText, node);

                this.setPlaceHolder(newText, index);
                this.translationStack.push(newText);
                this.resultStack.push(obj);
                this.textNodeCount--;
                if(this.textNodeCount <= 0)
                    this.finishTranslation(obj);
            }
            catch(e){
                console.log("Error has occured with handling translation error = %o arguments = %o", e, arguments);
            }

        }
    });
</script>
```

if you click on the `li` it sets the language and start the function:

```
    <ul id="langSelect">
  <li lang="de">German</li></ul>
```

another solution might be to similate a user click on the li command, but I am also not sure how to do this!

Any help would be appreciated.

Any help would be appreciated

I think part of the problem lies here:

```
triggerCollection.invoke("observe", "click", handleTriggerClick);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are interested in the [dom:loaded](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/document/observe/) event.

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
    translator.translate($('langselect').getAttribute('lang'));
});
```

Or if you know the language code you can feed it in directly. For the german example:

```
    translator.translate('de');
```

Comment: The function gets started by clicking on <ul id="langSelect">   <li lang="de">German</li></ul>

Comment: I have done it like this: <script> document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {document.getElementById('langselect').click(); // or whatever the starting command is }); </script> This simulates a click on the <ul id="langSelect"> <li lang="de">German</li></ul> and make the function work although it might not be the most elegant way of doing it!

Comment: Updated with the more elegant way. `document.getElementById` is too long and not all browsers will respond to `click()` as you might expect.